# My regular expression isn't matching correctly

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I'm using the following regular expression to match one or more special characters for a password strength test.

```
if (password.match(/\W+/)) points++;
```

This doesn't seem to match the underscore '_' as a special character.  Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `\W` is the same as `[^\w]`, while [`\w` contains `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `_`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word) as well.

In order to fix it just add `_` character separately:

```
if (password.match(/[\W_]+/)) points++;
```

Comment: +1 i was just writing that `\W` excludes alphabet, numbers and underscores !

Answer (score 2):

`\W` (uppercase) means `not \w`, so anything except word characters.

Word characters (`\w`) includes letters, digits, and underscore.

Perhaps you should use `/[^a-z0-9]+/i` to match non-letters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want the `\w`? The `\W` is the negation of `\w`.

`\w` matches (letters, digits, and underscores), so `\W` does NOT match letters, digits, and underscores. See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The match fails because underscore is treated as a word character. From the [MDN documentation for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `\W`:

> Matches any non-word character. Equivalent to [^A-Za-z0-9_]

You can fix this by grouping underscore and `\W`:

```
if (password.match(/[\W_]+/)) points++;
```

A regex tool such as [Javascript Regex Tester](http://www.cyber-reality.com/regexy.html) can be especially helpful for debugging this sort of thing.